# Use of OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 for Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, openmp

I heard that using `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` before calling a Python script that use multiprocessing make the script faster.

Is it true or not ? If yes, why so ?

Comment: `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is an option for [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), a C/C++/Fortran API for doing multi-threading within a process.  It's unclear how that's even related to Python multiprocessing.  Is your Python program calling modules written in C that use OpenMP internally?

Comment: Correct. That explain things ! So, I guess the option avoid python multiprocessing to call another process that is doing multiprocessing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you said in a comment that your Python program is calling a C module that uses [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP):

OpenMP does multi-threading within a process, and the default number of threads is typically the number that the CPU can actually run simultaneously.  (This is generally the number of CPU cores, or a multiple of that number if the CPU has an [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) feature such as Intel's Hyper-Threading.)  So if you have, for example, a quad-core non-hyperthreaded CPU, OpenMP will want to run 4 threads by default.

When you use Python's `multiprocessing` module, your program starts multiple Python processes which can run simultaneously.  You can control the number of processes, but often you'll want it to be the number of CPU cores/threads, e.g. returned by `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.

So, what happens on that quad-core CPU if you run a `multiprocessing` program that runs 4 Python processes, and each calls an OpenMP function runs 4 threads?  You end up running 16 threads on 4 cores.  That'll work, but not at peak efficiency, since each core will have to spend some time switching between tasks.

Setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` basically turns off the OpenMP multi-threading, so each of your Python processes remains single-threaded.

Make sure you're starting enough Python processes if you do this, though!  If you have 4 CPU cores and you only run 2 single-threaded Python processes, you'll have 2 cores utilized and the other 2 sitting idle.  (In this case you might want to set `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2`.)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in comments:

> OMP_NUM_THREADS is an option for OpenMP, a C/C++/Fortran API for doing multi-threading within a process.
>   It's unclear how that's even related to Python multiprocessing.
>   Is your Python program calling modules written in C that use OpenMP internally? – Wyzard