# multiprocessing with HF's transformers uses all CPU cores despite being limited num_workers

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, huggingface-transformers

I am using `torch.multiprocessing` to parallelize my for-loop as follows:

```py
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

torch.set_num_threads(1)
mp.set_start_method("spawn", force=True)

seqs = # List of strings

def func1(x):
    # Some numpy calculation
    return a, b

def func2(a, b):
    # Run initial computations with torch
    # Run forward inference of nn.Module (wrapper of transformers model)
    # Perform additional computations with torch
    return c

def main_func(x):
   a, b = func1(x)
   c = func2(a, b)
   return c


pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
results = pool.map(main_func, seqs)
```

In this code, `func1` performs some numpy calculations, while `func2` represents the forward call of an `nn.Module`, which wraps the [`EsmForMaskedLM`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/esm#transformers.EsmForMaskedLM) model.

Specifically, the mentioned `nn.Module` can be simplified as below

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, EsmForMaskedLM, BatchEncoding


class ESM2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ESM2, self).__init__()
        self.model = EsmForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("facebook/esm2_t12_35M_UR50D")
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/esm2_t12_35M_UR50D")
        self.model.to("cpu")

    def forward(self, inputs: BatchEncoding) -> torch.Tensor:
        results = self.model(**inputs)   # inputs has been tokenized and passed to CPU
        return results
```

When I run the code sequentially in a for-loop, everything works as expected. However, when I attempt to parallelize it using `torch.multiprocessing`, it seems to **occupy all CPU cores** in my machine, even though I have set a limit on the number of processes. Upon debugging, I found that this issue occurs only when calling `func2` (i.e., the `forward` function). I suspect there might be a problem with the `forward` function, but I'm uncertain. Can someone please assist me with this issue? Thank you very much for your help!

P/s: If you guys need any additional information, please let me know, I am happy to provide more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, PyTorch uses a parallelization library called `OpenMP` ([link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cpu_threading_torchscript_inference.html)); and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43897781/13139588):

> OpenMP does multi-threading within a process, and the default number of threads is typically the number that the CPU can actually run simultaneously
> ...
> So, what happens on that quad-core CPU if you run a multiprocessing program that runs 4 Python processes, and each calls an OpenMP function runs 4 threads? You end up running 16 threads on 4 cores

So when I set `os.environ["OPENMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"`, it performs as expected.

Other resources: [HF discussion](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/limit-predictions-computing-to-single-cpu-core/10828/2)